# How can I prevent Angular from rendering and displaying a page before ng-if evaluation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a code below that basically shows a block of code based on the "ng-if" evaluation(true/false). A problem I have is that even wehn vm.anyItems equals to true, AngularJS tries to render the `<p>...</p>` block and display it on a browser before the `<div>...</div>` is properly displayed. 
Are there any ways to prevent this?

```
<div ng-if="vm.anyItems">
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="!vm.anyItems">
    <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into ngCloak. This will stop your code from being displayed until after the application is rendered by Angular.

Your code can do the following:

```
<div ng-cloak ng-if="vm.anyItems">
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<div ng-cloak ng-if="!vm.anyItems">
    <p>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
</div>
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Did you try it in the p tag?